# How to create a background app (Service) to get the mobile data every 30 sec. The service must working in 24/7

Tags: android, service, timer

Currently I manage to do get every 30 sec received/transmitted across mobile networks since device boot.

`Timer` :-

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTimeTask, 0, AppConstants.DATA_TRACKING_PERIOD);

private TimerTask mTimeTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           long currentRx = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
           long currentTx = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        }
    }
};
```

`Service` :-

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (isInstanceCreated()) {
        if(!mSocket.connected()){
           connectConnection();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    connectConnection();
    //Timer starts from here
    mTrafficHelper.startTracking();    
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml` :-

```
<!-- Access network/ Internet connection permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<service android:name=".services.MyService"
         android:enabled="true"
         android:exported="true"
         android:priority="100" />
```

Is this the correct way to implement the above requirement? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that will keep a Service running 24/7.  The Android framework may kill a Service for resources at any time.

In addition, on more modern versions of Android you'll run into Doze mode.  Doze is a deep sleep mode to save battery power.  It will prevent your service from running every 30 seconds to preserve battery power.

There may be a way around it AlarmManager and using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle.  But this is NOT suggested for any Play Store app, you will kill your user's battery.

Really I'd question why you need to get the data so frequently.  Odds are you don't and are either over engineering or doing the wrong thing entirely.

Comment: Yes. you are 100% correct. But this is not my requirement. This is from client's requirement. And the app basically need to track mobile data usage at every 30 sec. Thanks for help!

Comment: Then push back on the client.  The job of an engineer is not just to blindly do what he's told-  its to advise and figure out what the client actually needs and what's technically possible.  If you're just taking requirements and writing code, you're doing less than half your job.

Comment: But after checking setExactAndAllowWhileIdle again, it won't work either-  there's limits on how frequently that's allowed on a per app basis.  It isn't allowed more than once a minute, and once per 15 minutes in Doze.  This just isn't possible on a modern version of Android.  Although you can get every 30 seconds while the phone is active, which is probably good enough.

Answer (score 0):

There is a another solution I found here and its not 100% answered my question.

[Android-Job](https://evernote.github.io/android-job/javadoc/)

Gradle: `app`

```
compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.3'
```

Code:

```
new JobRequest.Builder(SocketSyncJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(JobRequest.MIN_INTERVAL, JobRequest.MIN_FLEX)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiresDeviceIdle(true)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .setRequirementsEnforced(false)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your activity code

```
AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), ScanReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60, pi);
```

// receiver

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //start your service
    }
```

}

and manifest add this

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It will call your receiver in one minute 24/7 which is default time, either your app is open or not.

Comment: setRepeating won't work in Doze mode, and isn't going to run that frequently in any version 19+ due to the changes made to Alarms for power savings (timers get delayed and combined to save power with setRepeating).